# iPhone platform disappeared from configuration and build targets, can't add back unless i create a new solution

Tags: iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

So I have an app that's about 2 years old, works fine.  But I've been having a lot of issues with Xamarin Studio lately so i've completely re-built this solution in Visual Studio for Mac.  All was good for about 2 days then suddenly something weird happened.  Out of the blue my iPhone configurations disappeared and are no longer available for me to select for builds or see in the settings.

If I try to create a new configuration it doesn't even give me the option to select iPhone as a platform.  It only shows iPhoneSimulator.  But if I create a new blank solution all together, the default configuration has both iPhoneSimulator and iPhone in it. And that new blank solution allows me to add configurations with iPhone platforms.

**Here is what I see when I try to create a new configuration, notice that it doesn't even offer me iPhone as a configuration, only iPhoneSimulator**
[image]

**If I create a new blank solution, it offers me iPhone as an option**[image]

**See below for what my solution file and structure looks like:**

[image]

**Below is my solution file and solution/project structure:**

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2012
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "MobileClient.iOS", "MobileClient.iOS\MobileClient.iOS.csproj", "{7EEC6C4F-036E-4144-BBE9-6C01BECEA311}"
EndProject
Project("{D954291E-2A0B-460D-934E-DC6B0785DB48}") = "Mobile.API", "..\xamarin_mobile_api\Mobile.API.shproj", "{4520CB09-DBCB-4764-8E8C-4CBAA2CBAD6A}"
EndProject
Project("{D954291E-2A0B-460D-934E-DC6B0785DB48}") = "Mobile.iOS", "..\xamarin_mobile_ios\Mobile.iOS.shproj", "{10B1EF5A-0F37-4544-9327-902022A42BA4}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "AdjustBindingsiOS", "..\xamarin_mobile_api\3rdParty\Adjust\AdjustBindingsiOS\AdjustBindingsiOS.csproj", "{EF829C6D-7D00-4DF1-95C7-F3E54B164827}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Mixpanel", "..\xamarin_mobile_api\3rdParty\Mixpanel\Mixpanel.csproj", "{5E6FA2B8-D94C-4318-8A37-1E9D765CF71E}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|iPhoneSimulator = Debug|iPhoneSimulator
        Staging|iPhoneSimulator = Staging|iPhoneSimulator
        Production|iPhoneSimulator = Production|iPhoneSimulator
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {7EEC6C4F-036E-4144-BBE9-6C01BECEA311}.Debug|iPhoneSimulator.ActiveCfg = Debug|iPhoneSimulator
        {7EEC6C4F-036E-4144-BBE9-6C01BECEA311}.Debug|iPhoneSimulator.Build.0 = Debug|iPhoneSimulator
        {7EEC6C4F-036E-4144-BBE9-6C01BECEA311}.Staging|iPhoneSimulator.ActiveCfg = Staging|iPhoneSimulator
        {7EEC6C4F-036E-4144-BBE9-6C01BECEA311}.Staging|iPhoneSimulator.Build.0 = Staging|iPhoneSimulator
        {7EEC6C4F-036E-4144-BBE9-6C01BECEA311}.Production|iPhoneSimulator.ActiveCfg = Production|iPhoneSimulator
        {7EEC6C4F-036E-4144-BBE9-6C01BECEA311}.Production|iPhoneSimulator.Build.0 = Production|iPhoneSimulator
        {EF829C6D-7D00-4DF1-95C7-F3E54B164827}.Debug|iPhoneSimulator.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {EF829C6D-7D00-4DF1-95C7-F3E54B164827}.Debug|iPhoneSimulator.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {EF829C6D-7D00-4DF1-95C7-F3E54B164827}.Staging|iPhoneSimulator.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {EF829C6D-7D00-4DF1-95C7-F3E54B164827}.Staging|iPhoneSimulator.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {EF829C6D-7D00-4DF1-95C7-F3E54B164827}.Production|iPhoneSimulator.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {EF829C6D-7D00-4DF1-95C7-F3E54B164827}.Production|iPhoneSimulator.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {5E6FA2B8-D94C-4318-8A37-1E9D765CF71E}.Debug|iPhoneSimulator.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {5E6FA2B8-D94C-4318-8A37-1E9D765CF71E}.Debug|iPhoneSimulator.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {5E6FA2B8-D94C-4318-8A37-1E9D765CF71E}.Staging|iPhoneSimulator.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {5E6FA2B8-D94C-4318-8A37-1E9D765CF71E}.Staging|iPhoneSimulator.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {5E6FA2B8-D94C-4318-8A37-1E9D765CF71E}.Production|iPhoneSimulator.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {5E6FA2B8-D94C-4318-8A37-1E9D765CF71E}.Production|iPhoneSimulator.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(MonoDevelopProperties) = preSolution
        Policies = $0
        $0.TextStylePolicy = $1
        $1.inheritsSet = null
        $1.scope = application/vnd.apple-interface-builder
        $1.inheritsScope = text/plain
        $1.FileWidth = 120
        $1.TabsToSpaces = False
        $0.CSharpFormattingPolicy = $2
        $2.IndentSwitchBody = True
        $2.IndentCaseBody = False
        $2.IndentPreprocessorDirectives = False
        $2.AnonymousMethodBraceStyle = NextLine
        $2.PropertyGetBraceStyle = NextLine
        $2.PropertySetBraceStyle = NextLine
        $2.EventBraceStyle = NextLine
        $2.EventAddBraceStyle = NextLine
        $2.EventRemoveBraceStyle = NextLine
        $2.StatementBraceStyle = NextLine
        $2.ElseNewLinePlacement = NewLine
        $2.ElseIfNewLinePlacement = DoNotCare
        $2.WithinMethodDeclarationParentheses = True
        $2.AfterDelegateDeclarationParameterComma = True
        $2.scope = text/x-csharp
        $0.DotNetNamingPolicy = $3
        $0.TextStylePolicy = $4
        $4.inheritsSet = null
        $4.scope = application/config+xml
        $0.XmlFormattingPolicy = $5
        $5.inheritsSet = null
        $5.scope = application/vnd.apple-interface-builder
        $5.inheritsScope = application/xml
        $0.TextStylePolicy = $6
        $6.inheritsSet = null
        $6.scope = application/xml
        $0.XmlFormattingPolicy = $7
        $7.scope = application/xml
        $0.TextStylePolicy = $8
        $8.scope = text/plain
        $0.TextStylePolicy = $9
        $9.inheritsSet = null
        $9.scope = application/json
        $0.VersionControlPolicy = $10
        $0.TextStylePolicy = $11
        $11.inheritsSet = null
        $11.scope = application/vnd.apple-xcode-storyboard
        $0.XmlFormattingPolicy = $12
        $12.inheritsSet = null
        $12.scope = application/vnd.apple-xcode-storyboard
        $0.TextStylePolicy = $13
        $13.inheritsSet = null
        $13.scope = application/vnd.apple-interface-builder
        $0.XmlFormattingPolicy = $14
        $14.inheritsSet = null
        $14.scope = application/vnd.apple-interface-builder
        $0.StandardHeader = $15
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

**Just to test, I created a new blank iOS solution** from scratch inside Visual Studio for Mac.  Below is what that solution file looks like.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2012
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "asdfasdf", "asdfasdf\asdfasdf.csproj", "{398E03FF-50ED-4D8C-8845-A6077EFF0093}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "qweradfsxz", "qweradfsxz\qweradfsxz.csproj", "{ABB95F3F-67FA-48D4-89AB-8EAD30C69DE2}"
EndProject
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|iPhoneSimulator = Debug|iPhoneSimulator
        Release|iPhone = Release|iPhone
        Release|iPhoneSimulator = Release|iPhoneSimulator
        Debug|iPhone = Debug|iPhone
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
        {398E03FF-50ED-4D8C-8845-A6077EFF0093}.Debug|iPhoneSimulator.ActiveCfg = Debug|iPhoneSimulator
        {398E03FF-50ED-4D8C-8845-A6077EFF0093}.Debug|iPhoneSimulator.Build.0 = Debug|iPhoneSimulator
        {398E03FF-50ED-4D8C-8845-A6077EFF0093}.Release|iPhone.ActiveCfg = Release|iPhone
        {398E03FF-50ED-4D8C-8845-A6077EFF0093}.Release|iPhone.Build.0 = Release|iPhone
        {398E03FF-50ED-4D8C-8845-A6077EFF0093}.Release|iPhoneSimulator.ActiveCfg = Release|iPhoneSimulator
        {398E03FF-50ED-4D8C-8845-A6077EFF0093}.Release|iPhoneSimulator.Build.0 = Release|iPhoneSimulator
        {398E03FF-50ED-4D8C-8845-A6077EFF0093}.Debug|iPhone.ActiveCfg = Debug|iPhone
        {398E03FF-50ED-4D8C-8845-A6077EFF0093}.Debug|iPhone.Build.0 = Debug|iPhone
        {ABB95F3F-67FA-48D4-89AB-8EAD30C69DE2}.Debug|iPhoneSimulator.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {ABB95F3F-67FA-48D4-89AB-8EAD30C69DE2}.Debug|iPhoneSimulator.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
        {ABB95F3F-67FA-48D4-89AB-8EAD30C69DE2}.Release|iPhone.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {ABB95F3F-67FA-48D4-89AB-8EAD30C69DE2}.Release|iPhone.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {ABB95F3F-67FA-48D4-89AB-8EAD30C69DE2}.Release|iPhoneSimulator.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
        {ABB95F3F-67FA-48D4-89AB-8EAD30C69DE2}.Release|iPhoneSimulator.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
        {ABB95F3F-67FA-48D4-89AB-8EAD30C69DE2}.Debug|iPhone.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
        {ABB95F3F-67FA-48D4-89AB-8EAD30C69DE2}.Debug|iPhone.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Here are screenshots of what my solution's build target platform options look like.  Notice the iPhone deploy target disappeared. And in configuration mappings, the iPhone platform disappeared and the iPhoneSimulator is the only one available.

[image][image]

Below are screenshots of my test solution I made, notice there is an iPhone (my phone's name is LeetSauce) option as well as an iPhone option in the configuration mappings.

[image][image]

Any ideas how I broke this or how to fix it?

**------------------EDIT------------------**

So a user on the Xamarin forums showed me that you can manually type in "iPhone" into the platform box in the 1st screenshot.  That was helpful.  But I ended up just re-creating the solution and adding in all the files/resources/packages/components again.  I'm not able to reproduce the issue again, hopefully I don't see it anymore.  This "feels" like a bug that somehow my .sln and/or .csproj files became corrupt.  It's also possible that it was broken to begin with and that it working for 2 days was just a fluke.  Hoping it doesn't happen again.

Comment: I believe that visual studio for mac will only provide Iphone as a build configuration if a physical device with the correct iOS version is detected. I assume the device is connected and fully updated when you're looking for it as a build configuration?

Comment: It is a physical device, and it is the correct iOS + Xcode version.  I ended up re-building the solution from scratch again because I ran into some issues manually editing the solution and csproj files. I'm curious to see if this problem occurs again, since i'm still not sure what caused it.

Comment: Your having to do a lot of rebuilding lately, fingers crossed that settles down for you soon :D

Comment: I thought the dust had settled before after we switched over to Visual Studio... Hopefully this is the last time I have to re-build everything ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think the quick solution for this creates a new solution and create new projects with the same names of old projects. You don't need to add files to each project.

Then copy all config setting from the new project and paste to the old project and replace the GUID.

Comment: So I did end up rebuilding it.  I just feel I shouldn't have to keep rebuilding my solution since i've had to do that so many times in the last week :-(  I must be running into a bug.  Manually modifying the .sln and .csproj files gives me a headache, so I just created from scratch again.  A user on the Xamarin Forums showed me that you can actually type "iPhone" into the platform pop up in the first screenshot.  So if it ever gets removed (for who knows what reason) you can add it back that way.